# Print an integer and its digits reversed

Tags: strings, lisp, common-lisp

This Common Lisp program is an exercise to print an integer and its digits reversed to the screen:

```
(defun read-number () (format t "Enter a number: ~%") (read))

(defun reverse-string (the-string) 
  (if (eq (length the-string) 0) 
    "" 
    (concatenate 'string (reverse-string (subseq the-string 1)) (subseq the-string 0 1))))

(defun reverse-digits (the-number) (reverse-string (write-to-string the-number)))

(let ((the-number (read-number)))
  (format t "N->: ~a~%<-N: ~a~%" the-number (reverse-digits the-number)))
```

Comment: Wow, lots of Lisp exercises. Is this for school, or did you just pick it up for the hell of it? :)

Comment: Just picked it up for the heck of it :)  I've always heard Lisp is a good language to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is more about numbers than strings, so I felt the need to post a non-string-based solution. I've got my original Scheme version, and a Common Lisp adaptation of same.

Scheme version:

```
(define (reverse-digits n)
  (let loop ((n n) (r 0))
    (if (zero? n) r
        (loop (quotient n 10) (+ (* r 10) (remainder n 10))))))
```

Common Lisp translation of the Scheme version:

```
(defun reverse-digits (n)
  (labels ((next (n v)
             (if (zerop n) v
                 (multiple-value-bind (q r)
                     (truncate n 10)
                   (next q (+ (* v 10) r))))))
    (next n 0)))
```

Comment: I meanwhile wrote my own version of `quotient`, `idiv`. `remainder` and `module` seem to be synonyms.

Comment: @user unknown: `remainder` and `modulo` have different behaviour if the dividend is negative. `(remainder -5 3)` => -2, whereas `(modulo -5 3)` => 1.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't test negative values. For such, I would use a wrapper method. `(if (< 0 x) (* -1 (redigit (* -1 x) 0)))`

Comment: +1 - Just keep in mind that TCO isn't guaranteed in CL the way it is in Scheme.

Comment: @Inaimathi: Of course. But how many digits is your number going to have? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about digits and integer, but to me, as an non-lisper, it looks as if you operate on Strings.

- I would take the number, modulo 10, print that digit.
- If the rest is > 0 recursively call the function with the (number - digit) / 10.

In most languages with integer-arithmetic you can omit the subtraction, since 37/10 => 3 :==: (37-7)/10 => 3

In scala it would look like this:

```
def redigit (n: Int, sofar: Int = 0) : Int = { 
     if (n == 0) sofar else                     
     redigit (n / 10, sofar * 10 + n % 10)}

redigit (123)
321
```

It uses default arguments. First tests with DrScheme didn't succeed. Here is what I came up with:

```
;; redigit : number number -> number
(define (redigit in sofar)
  (cond [(< in 1) sofar]
      [else (redigit (/ in 10) (+ (* 10 sofar) (modulo in 10)))]) 
)

(redigit 134 0)
```

But the division is precise and doesn't cut off the digits behind the floting point. I get this error:

> modulo: expects type  as 1st
>   argument, given: 67/5; other arguments
>   were: 10

I looked for a function toInt, asInt, floor, round and so on for the term (/ in 10) but I didn't find something useful. Maybe you know it yourself?

Comment: You need to use `quotient` and `remainder`. See my answer. :-)